# ¿Como separar cantidades de miles y decimales por "," y ".", usando toLocaleString?

Tags: jquery

Buen día:
Tengo las siguientes cantidad

```
var num = 54
var num2 = 1325
var num3 = 1293824
```

al aplicar toLocaleString quedan de la siguiente forma:

```
num.toLocaleString(undefined, {minimumFractionDigits: 2}) // Resultado 54,00
num2.toLocalString(undefined, {minimumFractionDigits: 2}) // 1.325,00
num3.toLocalString(undefined, {minimumFractionDigits: 2}) // 12.938,24
```

Cuando los resultados los necesito de la siguiente forma:

```
54.00 
1,325.00 
12,938.24
```

Separador para miles debe ser ","
Separador para decimales debe ser "."

De antemano muy agradecido.

Comment: Se llaman formatos de moneda, y aunque no encontré ninguno que se acomoda exactamente a lo que necesitas, puedes utilizar el código creado en este [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-dollars-currency-string-in-javascript) Como podrás encontrar, se puede crear una función la cual cumpla con lo que necesitas. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar lo siguiente:

```js
var number = 12345.67;
var result = number.toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,');
console.log(result);
```

- `.toFixed(2)` es el numero de decimales que quieres dejar despues del
  punto.
- `.replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,');` es una expresión
  regular que añade la coma despues de un grupo de 3 digitos.

Saludos!

[Fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14428340/8067370)

Answer (score 0):

Intenta esto:

```js
function addCommas(nStr)
{
    nStr += '';
    x = nStr.split('.');
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    return x1 + x2;
}

var valor = (1325).toFixed(2);
console.log(addCommas(valor));
valor = (1325.25).toFixed(2);
console.log(addCommas(valor));
```